# gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function

Tags: ubuntu, wget, curl, gnutls

I have a problem with my Ubuntu (Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS) server. It is very strange. When I try to use any tool for fetching a specific URL over ssl it fails. Examples:

CURL

```
curl -v https://www.netonnet.se/
*   Trying 91.198.164.24...
* Connected to www.netonnet.se (91.198.164.24) port 443 (#0)
* found 148 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 596 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function.
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function.
```

WGET

```
wget -v https://www.netonnet.se/
--2018-12-29 12:00:42--  https://www.netonnet.se/
Resolving www.netonnet.se (www.netonnet.se)... 91.198.164.24
Connecting to www.netonnet.se (www.netonnet.se)|91.198.164.24|:443... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection
```

Any other way I try to access this website also fails so it must be something deeper, these requests are successful on all other servers I tried it on. It affects all users on this sever. I don't use any proxys on this server. How do I debug this?

EDIT

This is what I get when I try openssl. There seems to be something wrong with fetching the certificate from the host.

```
# openssl s_client  -servername www.netonnet.se -connect www.netonnet.se:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 317 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Resumption PSK:
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1546109807
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
---
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some analysis I have come to the conclusion that the reason must be one of:

1. That host has blocked my IP from opening connections on port 443.
2. Some kind of firewall has blocked me from opening connections on port 443.

I solved it by using another server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to lower your MTU.

`ifconfig <Interface_name> mtu <mtu_size> up`

In my case, 1400 worked well.

`ifconfig ens3 mtu 1400 up`

My environment is Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Had similar error when faced with 'proxy_protocol' turned on and on ELB the proxy protocol is disabled. Enable the ELB proxy protocol.

- Check web server logs for more details example /var/log/nginx/error.log

you might see error like this

```
2020/06/20 20:31:02 [error] 12071#12071: *149 broken header: "" while reading PROXY protocol, client: 62.54.78.90, server: 0.0.0.0:3344
```